# Vue V-Model Initiation Losses Selects Selection

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, html-select, v-model

I'm having an issue initializing Vue on certain types of html elements, take a look at the following code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Without Vue:
  <!-- Non-Vue select defaults to selected value -->
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  <br /> 
  <br /> 
  
  With Vue:
  <!-- Vue enabled list loses selection -->
  <select v-model="test">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I start Vue, it seems any "selects" you declare the v-Modal on lose their selected value. This is as described in [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the
> JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

Now I can do this, but for each select I now need to write a bit of JS outside of Vue to populate/repopulate the selects default value(by populating the "data" property, or reselecting the previously selected value post Vue deceleration).

Is there an easier way of doing this? Maybe some sort of option or tag I can feed to Vue to "persist" values inherited from the initial state of the HTML control?

Comment: why not assign the data property= **test** with one default value same as one of the options like `test: 2`?

Comment: Yeah I've done something like `var XXX = $('#XXX').val(); ... vueObject.data = XXX` but mostly the same thing, yes your approach would work probably better than the more hacky workaround I've used. I know there's ways to get around the behavior, I'd just like something a little easier. It becomes quite tedious with large user forms with many drop downs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@b0nyb0y answer is technically correct, but since it doesn't solve my specific issue I'd figure I'd include my hacky workaround here for future reference(only works for selects):

```
var itemsToRestore = [];
$('select[v-model]').each(function (index, value) {
    itemsToRestore.push({
        vModelProperty: $(value).attr("v-model"),
        selectedValue: $(value).val()
    });
});

var thisVue = new Vue({
    //Put your vue code here
});

itemsToRestore.forEach(function (value) {
    thisVue[value.vModelProperty] = value.selectedValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To take advantage of `vue`'s reactivity system, `vue` needs full control. So there's no way around it, you have to inform `vue` about these default values somehow.

If you're html-centric, then it'll be a bit awkward: you have to select `dom` element to find its default value and set it back into `vue`. That'd work, but it will be unidiomatic.

The proper way in `vue` is to go full data-driven, and construct HTML based on the data. For example, if your form have 2 select boxes, then with `vue`'s way, you should define data for all `option`s you have, and use such data to generate these elements from scratch (please note that I'm using `Single File Component` format here):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Select :items="list1"/>
    <Select :items="list2"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import Select from './components/Select.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      list1: [
        { id: 1, name: "spoon" },
        { id: 2, name: "fork", preselect: true },
        { id: 3, name: "knife" }
      ],
      list2: [
        { id: 4, name: "macbook" },
        { id: 5, name: "dell" },
        { id: 6, name: "lenovo", preselect: true }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: { Select }
};
</script>
```

And, here's the code for `<Select>` component (note that this is a custom Vue component, as it starts with a capital `S`). This component will receive prop `items`, and automatically calculate the selected value from the items given:

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option 
      v-for="item of items"
      :key="item.id"
      :value="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: ["items"],
  data() {
    return {
      // pre-select item from 'items'
      selected: this.items.filter(item => item.preselect)[0].id
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

With that done, item `fork` and item `lenovo` will be pre-selected as data dictates. You can also see a working example on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1q34qk24k4).

Comment: Yes, that would be great if I wasn't trying to implement on top of a legacy webforms application, right now my challenge is to put vue on top of a bunch of "asp:DropDownList", maybe I'll need to redo all of it...

Comment: @DavidRogers I feel your pain. When you decide to go full idiomatic Vue some day, if you have also been doing web scraping/ e2e testing with `selenium` or `puppeteer`, you can definitely create a script to find all of the `<input>` or `<select>` elements and construct data from there. For big forms in a really big legacy app, it's too much to construct JSON by hand.